# Load an external script via $timeout when the ng-switch-when of the directive is triggered

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have a directive created as follow:

```
elements.directive('myApp', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/path/to/myapp.html",
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            // loads the script when the dom has finished rendering
        var loadScript = function() {
            var script = document.getElementById('myappjs');
            if(script){
                /*
                 * the script is already appended but needs to be re-executed
                 * - remove and re-append the script element?
                 * - $route.reload() in order to refresh the page?
                 * - other solutions
                */
            } else {
                // the script has never been loaded before and the script element is created from scratch
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.id = "myappjs";
                s.src = '/path/to/require.js';
                s.setAttribute('data-main', '/path/to/script');  //.js needs to be omitted

                document.body.appendChild(s);
            }
        };
        // when the DOM has finished rendering, loadScript is executed:
        $timeout(loadScript, 0);
    }
};
});
```

The 'my-app' element is putted within a ng-switch container. Basically it loads an svg and the script to execute it. 
The problem is that  the script is executed only the first time the ng-switch matches the 'my-app' element: if I switch to 'my-app' from another directive (always within the ng-switch container) it works. 
But if I move again to the other directive and then again to 'my-app', the script doesn't work anymore.

I tried to use $route.reload() when it founds that the script has been already appended before, but it causes an infinite loop.
Then I tried to remove the script element from the DOM and re-append it, but the script doesn't load anyway.

So the content of the svg is loaded only the first time I go to the page.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you pass whatever values you have to the scope and manipulate the data within the directive?

Comment: In the end I solved by wrapping all the code of the external JS within a run function. The first time is executed within the external file itself. Then it's executed within the directive every time ng-switch matches the directive.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by wrapping all the code of the external JS within a run function:

```
/* app.js file */

var myAppRun = function() {
    /* the code of my app  */
}
myAppRun();
```

the HTML switch:

```
<!-- select-page-template.html file -->
<div ng-switch on="selectedPage">
    <my-app ng-switch-default></my-app>     
    <another-directive ng-switch-when="another_directive"></another-directive>
</div>
```

and the directive definition:

```
/* directives.js file*/
elements.directive('myApp', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "/path/to/myapp.html",
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            var loadScript = function() {
                if(typeof myAppRun === "function"){
                myAppRun();
                return;
            }

                var s = document.createElement('script');
                    s.src = '/path/to/myapp.js';
                document.body.appendChild(s);
            };

                $timeout(loadScript, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

If myAppRun function has not yet been defined, the script will be created and appended to the HTML body. myAppRun() will be automatically executed within the myapp.js file.
Otherwise myAppRun() will be called within the directive controller every time ng-switch matches the default condition.

'loadScript'  is executed only after the DOM has been rendered using $timeout. In this way myapp.js can find all the elements (for instance a SVG element within the myapp template) that needs to manipulate without throwing 'element not found' errors.